# Prove that $\{1, (x-2), (x-2)^2, ... , (x-2)^n\}$ is a basis of all polynomial functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ at most $n$ degree.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the real vector space of all polynomial functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ at most $n$ degree. That is, the space of all functions with form $f(x)=c_0+c_1x+...+c_nx^n$ with $c_i\in\mathbb{R}$

I need to prove that $\{1, (x-2), (x-2)^2, ... , (x-2)^n\}$ is a basis of $V$. For that, first I need to prove the linear independence which I can do. Well, here is where I get stuck.
How can I prove, that this set spans $V$?
My first thought was to use induction, but I'm struggling to write it somehow.
Could someone please advise me how to do this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the dimension of $V$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you, you are not looking for a final solution, but only for directions to solve it. So here are some directions:

You know that $A_n=\{1, x, x^2, \ldots, x^n\}$ is a basis of your vector space $V$ if you can show

1. that the elements of $B_n=\{1, (x-2), (x-2)^2, \ldots, (x-2)^n\}$ can be expressed as linear combination of the elements of $A_n$, and
2. that the elements of $A_n$ can be expressed as can be expressed as linear combination of the elements of $B_n$,

you are done.

The first point should come from the binomial theorem. For the second direction, induction might come in handy: if you assume that the this holds for $A_{n-1}$ and $B_{n-1}$ and use $(x-2)^n=(x-2)(x-2)^{n-1}$ you should be able to find a solution.

###### Alternative

By substituting $x=y+2$, one gets $A_n=\{1, (y+2), (y+2)^2, \ldots, (y+2)^n\}$ and $B_n=\{1, y, y^2, \ldots, y^n\}$. Point 2 can now also be shown with the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use [Taylor's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) at point 2. The formula at order n is exact for polynomials of degree n or less and will give you the decomposition you are looking for.